# How to get alternating value colums in a Pandas Pivot Table?

Tags: python, pandas, report, pivot-table

I'd like to generate a report from a Pandas DataFrame that uses alternating value columns as opposed to alternating the main column.  For example, given this code:

```
import pandas as pd
data = [('a1', 'b1', 1, 2),
        ('a1', 'b2', 3, 4),
        ('a1', 'b3', 5, 6),
        ('a2', 'b1', 7, 8),
        ('a2', 'b2', 9, 10),
        ('a2', 'b3', 11, 12)]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['A', 'B', 'X', 'Y'])
print(pd.pivot_table(df, index='A', columns=['B']))
```

I get this output:

```
    X         Y        
B  b1 b2  b3 b1  b2  b3
A                      
a1  1  3   5  2   4   6
a2  7  9  11  8  10  12
```

but, I'd prefer something like this:

```
B  b1    b2      b3 
    X  Y  X   Y   X  Y        
A                      
a1  1  2  3   4   5   6
a2  7  8  9  10  11  12
```

Any reasonable way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to do is swap the levels on your MultiIndex dataframe. Then you have to sort it.

```
In [1]: pd.pivot_table(df, index='A', columns=['B']).swaplevel(axis=1).sort_index(axis=1)
Out[1]:
B  b1    b2      b3
     X  Y  X   Y   X   Y
A
a1  1  2  3   4   5   6
a2  7  8  9  10  11  12
```